# Privacy Policy for web form that does not save to database

Tags: privacy

I'm making a website for a local business that has a simple contact form.

If the information from the form is simply sent to an email address such as test@hotmail.co.uk and not saved in a database, then surely no personal data is being collected and stored?

Trying to understand whether I need to mention that people's data is collected through a simple form but not stored.

Therefore would I just be able to simply state:

**Privacy Policy:**

We don't store your data.

Answer (score 1):

The data is being collected, it's just not stored in your database but in your email's inbox.

As long as you collect the data (web form) and have access to it (email inbox), then a Privacy Policy is required.

Simply disclose what information you collect and why in your Privacy Policy. Example from [Refinery29](https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/privacy):

[image]